# actualizar una base de datos sql en c# con origen de datos acces, exel, vfp

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, ms-access, visual-foxpro

Hola quiero lanzar esta pregunta buscando un poco de ayuda. Tengo una base de datos en vfp donde hay una tabla llamada contrato donde estan las columnas area,descrip,nc y aa_cont y tengo que enviar los datos por medio de una data set a sql en c#.Esto ya lo pude hacer con el comando SqlBulkCopy, pero ahora quiero que al momento de ingresar una nueva fila de datos en vfp tambien me la llene en sql y con SqlBulkCopy me manda todos los datos de la tabla duplicando los existentes en la tabla sql, asi que investigando sobre el tema implemente este codigo pero me lanza un mensaje sobre que no se puede acceder a la base de datos. esto esparecido a conectlo a una base de datos acces o exel. que puedo hacer o que metodo puedo utilizar para realizar esta accion?

```
using (SqlConnection targetConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = 11.11.111.111; Initial Catalog = prueba; User ID = root; Password = root"))
        {
            targetConn.Open();

            //Crear tabla temporal
            // string consultaSQL = "CREATE TABLE #excontrato (...)";
            // string consultaSQL = "CREATE TABLE DORY (AREA NCHAR(255)null,Descrip text null,Nc nchar(255) null,Aa_cont nchar(255) null)";
            string consultaSQL = " select Area, Descrip, Nc, Aa_cont from CRE where aa_cont = 2019";

            //CREATE TABLE CRE(AREA NCHAR(255)null,Descrip text null,Nc nchar(255) null,Aa_cont nchar(255) null)
            var cmd = new SqlCommand(consultaSQL, targetConn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //Insertar datos en tabla temporal
            using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(targetConn.ConnectionString))
            {
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "CRE";
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dsContrato.Tables[0]); //Esc'ribir el origen de los datos
            }

            //Actualizar...
            //cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE T SET <...> FROM T t1 INNER JOIN #TempTable ON <...>; 
            //DROP TABLE #TempTable";

            cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE CRE SET Area = @ Area, ,Descrip = @Descrip, ,Nc = @Nc, ,Aa_cont = @Aa_cont WHERE aa_cont=>2019  DROP TABLE CRE";

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Genera dos métodos diferentes uno para registrarlo en tu vfp y otro para registrarlo en sql, es mejor que los tengas en diferentes métodos para trabajar mejor con ellos y no que uno dispare a otro, en todo caso seria mejor que leas sobre los join, y uses un left join para solo guardar lo nuevo de la tabla, coméntame que idea te agrada mas y seguimos con el tema.

Comment: muchas gracias me bares las opciones, me gustaria saber mas sobre como usar el left join  para guardar lo nuevo de la tabla